# Python.Net using .NET Core Runtime instead of Mono on Linux

Tags: python.net

Is it possible to load a net core dll on Python and Linux, by using Python.Net, but relying on the .NET Core Runtime instead of mono?

Seems it is not possible:

```
Collecting pythonnet==2.4.0
  Downloading pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-33weh4lj/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-33weh4lj/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vikr8ffc
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-33weh4lj/pythonnet/
  Complete output (43 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  /bin/sh: 1: mono: not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: There is progress on supporting .NET 5
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282510/is-net-core-or-net-5-0-supported-by-pythonnet

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1157#issuecomment-641179234