# Pythonnet dotnet core 'No module named'

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I am trying to use a .NET Core library inside a Jupyter Notebook python script by using PythonNet. Support for .NET Core was added recently (see https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/984#issuecomment-778786164) but I am still getting a `No module named 'TestAppCore'` error.

I don't have an issue using a .NET Framework library with PythonNet, only .NET Core. Any help with diagnosing and fixing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

The C# library I'm trying to get working is a simple class library project with no dependencies at all. Below is the entirety of the code:

```
namespace TestAppCore
{
  public class Foo
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public Foo(int id)
    {
      ID = id;
    }
    
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
      return a + b;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the python script:

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime

rt = get_coreclr("D:\src\Test.runtimeconfig.json")
set_runtime(rt)

import clr
import sys

sys.path.append(r"D:\src\TestAppCore")
clr.AddReference(r"TestAppCore")

from TestAppCore import Foo

foo = Foo(5)
print(foo.ID)

res = foo.Add(1, 2)
print(res)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Finally, here is the runtime config I am using:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

- .NET Core: 3.1
- python version: 3.7
- pythonnet: 3.0.0.dev1
- clr-loader: 0.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are getting the DLL path wrong.
This worked for me:

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime
set_runtime(get_coreclr("pythonnetconfig.json"))
import clr
clr.AddReference("C:/Path/To/Interface.dll")

from Interface import Foo
foo = Foo()
```

Using

```
Python 3.8.10
pythonnet 3.0.0a1
clr-loader 0.1.7
```

C# DLL (Class Library) targeting .NET Core 3.1

pythonnetconfig.json exactly as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I never got it to work with .NET Core 3.1. For me it worked with .NET Framework 4.8 and pythonnet 2.5.2. [See my other answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584450/6329629).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and found out that if the DLL and the namespace are the same, then it fails. In my case, following pythonnet tutorial:

```
Calculate.sln contains Calc.cs, with

namespace Calculate;  // recommended by VS
class Calc { ... }
```

Then in Python

```
clr.AddReference("Calculate") # Assuming sys.path correct setting
from Calculate import Calc
```

Then:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Calc' from 'Calculate' (unknown location)

But with:

```
namespace CalculateNS;  // different name than Calculate.dll
class Calc { ... }
```

Then in Python

```
clr.AddReference("Calculate") # Assuming sys.path correct setting
from CalculateNS import Calc
```

it works... side effects, pylance known Calculate module but not CalculateNS :-(

Anyone experimented this? I saw lot of answers that have never been tested I guess, only thoughts

Using .NET 6.0 Framework.